# Windows 10 update problem on Nokia 926

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I need help I was trying to download w10 using windows insider app to get the update and I did all of the first steps then the phone said rebooting and went to spinning gears screen with progress bar and turned off within 10 seconds and I restarted the phone multiple times but still does exact same thing